# I don't have the right arguments for AddModulesAsync (C# Discord.Net)

Tags: c#, .net-core, discord, discord.net, netcoreapp3.0

I followed this tutorial ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccsf5Rcu9mM ) on how to make a discord bot in `C#`. Everything went fine until the *57:02* timestamp (the last step before getting it done). I get an error in the following line of code: `await commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());`. It tells me that the argument is incorrect. VS suggest me to use `AddModuleAsync()` instead of `AddModulesAsync()`, but then it throws another error related to the arguments.

By the way, the only thing that isn't as in the tutorial is that I seem to have `.Net Core 3.0` instead of 2.0 as in the video.

Comment: Make sure you add `using Discord.Commands;` to your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In latest stable version of Discord.net signature changed. Now you need add `IServiceProvider` as second argument. So you code must look like this

`await commands.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), _services);`

Where `_services` is `IServiceProvider`;